# How do I run a binary in kernel mode? CPL = 0

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64

I have a binary that does a tlb flush by

`mov eax, cr3 mov cr3, eax` 
But that needs CPL 0, how do I set that?

I’m on Linux.

I tried finding an instruction to change CPL or a way to run it like su but came up empty.

Comment: Build it into a kernel module and load it into the kernel.  You can't run a normal executable in ring 0 (CPL 0) under Linux, AFAIK.  `root` (UID=0) is still user-space CPL=3.  The most you can do is run in user-space with IOPL=0, allowing `cli` / `sti` and `in`/`out` to any port, but not privileged instructions in general.

Comment: On a system using process context IDs (PCIDs) like Linux does, reloading `cr3` with the same value won't flush TLB entries.  TLB entries are tagged with the PCID (and logical processor number) so they can survive context switches.

Comment: SMAP e SMEP are two additional features that will make it harder to trick the kernel into running userspace code. Executing a process at CPL=0 is not possible for all I know. The Linux kernel is simply not designed that way (in which context would this process run?). You are better off isolating the code that requires kernel privileges in an LKM and exposing a proper user-kernelspace interface.